# CSS DIV position problem (2 divs with absolute position)

Tags: html, css

I set up 2 divs with some backgrounds and I want to set div2 under div 1, but I don't know how to do this, please help. Now, div2 is over div1 and div1 is invisible on this website.

```css
.div1 {
      perspective: 100px;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: -51%;
    }
    
    .div2 {
      perspective: 100px;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: -51%;
    }
```

```html
<div class='div1'>Some very important text...</div>
<div class='div2'>Not so important text...</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the divs in exactly the same position?  If so why not just nest them.  If not please can you clarify what the problem is as it isn't very clear.  Things to clarify - when you say underneath, do you mean there is some overlap, or do you mean that div one is at the top of the page and div to is at the bottom of the page?  Explain the context of why you are using absolute positioning - you shouldn't really use if for layout

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you, I added a `top: 100%;` to `div2`.

```css
.div1 {
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -51%;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; /*Changed*/
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -51%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div1::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
 
.div2::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">a</div>
<div class="div2">a</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but I have 3 scrolls, 2 for div content and 1 for all page.

Comment: Add this the code .div1::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}

.div2::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
} Let me know if that helps